# SQLite queries not executing in a particular order

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been trying to execute several SQLite queries one after the other on Android, but I get an odd error. I managed to make the supposingly broken query after pasting it to an SQL validator but then one of the queries I am successfully executing is very similar. So here's the queries in the order I am executing them:

```
   1.
   CREATE TABLE companyD (companyD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   name TEXT)

   2.
   CREATE TABLE personD (personD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   name TEXT, 
   age INTEGER, 
   companyD_Key INTEGER, 
   FOREIGN KEY(companyD_Key) REFERENCES companyD(companyD_ID))

   3.
   CREATE TABLE vehicleD (vehicleD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   make TEXT, 
   model TEXT, 
   personD_Key INTEGER, 
   FOREIGN KEY(personD_Key) REFERENCES personD(personD_ID))

   4.
   CREATE TABLE addressD (addressD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   buildingName TEXT, 
   address_1 TEXT, 
   address_2 TEXT, 
   address_3 TEXT, 
   postcode TEXT, 
   county TEXT, 
   country TEXT, 
   companyD_Key INTEGER, 
   FOREIGN KEY(companyD_Key) REFERENCES companyD(companyD_ID), 
   personD_Key INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(personD_Key) REFERENCES personD(personD_ID))
```

Following is the error message:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "personD_Key": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE addressD (addressD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, buildingName TEXT, address_1 TEXT, address_2 TEXT, address_3 TEXT, postcode TEXT, county TEXT, country TEXT, companyD_Key INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(companyD_Key) REFERENCES companyD(companyD_ID), personD_Key INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(personD_Key) REFERENCES personD(personD_ID))
```

I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with my fourth query, so any help would be appreciated,
Thanks,
:))

Comment: So wrap them in begin...end for each table create script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table constraints such as `FOREIGN KEY(...) REFERENCES ...` come after column definitions. You're mixing a column def `personD_Key INTEGER` between two `FOREIGN KEY` table constraints.

[image]

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html